# remove list of specific characters from string php

Tags: php, arrays, string

```
$string = "' ! ; • ,\ KarSho: ; • ;}";
```

Here I want remove following characters,

```
$remove = array("'","!",";","•",",","\","}","{","[","]");
```

This is also input. I want from above array characters from **$string**. Finally I want string like,

> **KarSho:**

Comment: the issue is the backslash ,"\","}","{","[","]");  try add extra " before \ sign..
like ""\"

Comment: Look at the `str_replace()` solution (And don't forget to escape the backslash)

Comment: $new_string = str_replace($remove,"",$string);

Answer (score 2):

Use the following code:

```php
$remove = ["'","!",";","•",",","\\","}","{","[","]"," "];
$replace_with = [];
$string = "' ! ; • ,\ KarSho: ; • ;}";
print str_replace($remove, $replace_with, $string);
```

You need to add one more \ with \

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```
$string = "' ! ; • ,\ KarSho: ; • ;}";
echo $new_str = str_replace(str_split('\\/!;•,}:*?"<>|'), ' ', $string);
```